# Using first() on Eloquent Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Good day. I saw this snippet in a code I am maintaining. I am trying to wrap my head around what it means (like if I even have to explain it to someone). Who can help simplify?
The code is shown below.

```
public function pullFrom(string $appType)
    {
        switch ($appType) {
            case 'personal':
            case 'plugin':
                return $this->belongsTo(PersonalUser::class, 'local_id')->first();
            default:
                throw new \Exception('Invalid user type provided', Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Is it same as saying `$user->pullFrom($app_type)->first();`

Comment: Is this in a Model called User.php?

Comment: what do you think this code "means", does? your question doesn't make sense to say "is the method the same as calling the method" ...

Comment: Yes @GilesBennett, it is in a model called User.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove the ->first() from the belongsTo relationship
by default belongsTo returns only 1 element of the class it has relation with, as well as remove it from the call you do:

```
public function pullFrom(string $appType)
    {
        switch ($appType) {
            case 'personal':
            case 'plugin':
                return $this->belongsTo(PersonalUser::class, 'local_id');
            default:
                throw new \Exception('Invalid user type provided', Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```